# dplyr mutate fails with named vector?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm surprised to see that `dplyr's` `mutate` function is failing when I feed it a named vector. In this case it's the residuals from a model. Is this expected behavior? Oddly it seems to work fine if the named vector is not coming directly from a data.frame. Also works fine if I remove names.

```
toy <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100))
mod <- lm(y~x, data = toy)

# Error: invalid subscript type 'list'
toy <- mutate(toy, fit = mod$fit, res = mod$res)

# Fine
fit <- mod$fit
res <- mod$res
toy <- mutate(toy, fit = fit, res = res)

# Fine
toy <- mutate(toy, fit = unname(mod$fit), res = unname(mod$res))
```

**UPDATE:**

I followed up on some of the suggestions and they do not seem to work. `plyr` is not loaded (I also tried dplyr::mutate to make double sure). I am using 0.4.2. Here's a screenshot with the session info.

[image]

Comment: works for me with dplyr 0.4.2. ...

Comment: do you have the plyr package loaded as well? Try dplyr::mutate instead of just mutate.

Comment: I see the same (yes 0.4.2; no plyr), but then `mutate(toy, fit = (mod$fit), res = (mod$res))` works. Seems like a bug, anyway.

Comment: Very interesting... For me it works as  `mutate(toy, fit = mod$fit, res = mod$res) ` but not as  `mutate(toy, fit = mod$fitted.values, res = mod$residuals) ` where it says `Error: invalid subscript type 'closure'`. Still version 0.4.2; no plyr.

Comment: Oddly neither work for me: `mutate(toy, fit = mod$fit, res = mod$res)` gives `Error: invalid subscript type 'double'` and `mutate(toy, fit = mod$fitted.values, res = mod$residuals)` gives `Error: invalid subscript type 'closure'`. dplyr 0.4.2, no plyr.

Comment: Mine runs `require(dplyr); mutate(toy, fit = mod$fit, res = mod$res);` with no errors.  Then, `mutate(toy, fit = mod$fitted.values, res = mod$residuals)` give the 'closure' error.  And then running `mutate(toy, fit = mod$fit, res = mod$res)` again gives me an invalid subscript 'double' error where the same command worked before.  dplyr 0.4.2. no plyr

Comment: I think it has to do with how the information flows when using `$` in a linear regression model object. It works when you do  `fitted.values(mod)` and  `residuals(mod)`.

Comment: @BenBolker are you on a Mac? The exact code is working for you?

Comment: works for me with dplyr 0.4.2 on MacOS (R 3.2.2) and Ubuntu (R-devel).  Does it work if you call `mod` something else, such as `mmm`?  `magrittr` has a `mod` function that might be getting found instead??

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! No, unfortunately, changing to mod2 does not work. Perhaps I'll report to Hadley on GitHub and see what he says.

Comment: This persists. It seems like a namespace lookup; `fitted.values()` is also a function. The issue can be replicated with a variable also. I've filed my own issue since yours was closed and it still happens in the bleeding edge version https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/2420