# Getting multiple sub-totals & group_by in a table form in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset (a CSV) of phone calls. It contains several columns but the important columns are "Persons calling" and "Persons called". The data is all strings (names). The entire work done is on these strings of two column data. As in example:

```
Caller  Receiver
Alice   Mary
Kate    Betty
Alice   Betty
Mary    Kate | Jane
Jane    Alice
```

The output desired is in the form of the number of calls made by a person and the persons made to. For instance, the output for above would be like:

```
Caller  Receiver    CallFreq
Alice   Mary        1
        Betty       1
Kate    Betty       1
Mary    Kate        1
        Jane        1
Jane    Alice       1
```

The Total calls made by the person could be included in the above table or in another table.

Comment: what's the form of your input? first of all, you need to make the data readable.

Comment: I have added some more details to Q. Simply, its a CSV with multiple columns. But my work is confined to two columns of names/strings (caller, receiver). I am trying to group these names and count frequency to arrive at a similar output as shown. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MrFlick!!!

Answer (score 0):

The unnest function from the tidyr package is super useful in this case.

```
output <-
  mydata %>% 
  group_by(Caller) %>%
  summarise(Receiver = paste(unique(Receiver), collapse=' | ')) %>%
  mutate(Receiver = strsplit(Receiver, ' \\| ')) %>%
  unnest(Receiver) %>%
  group_by(Caller) %>%
  mutate(CallFreq = 1, TotalCalls = n_distinct(Receiver))
```

To run the above code directly, you'd need to use the packages dplyr, magrittr, and tidyr.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the code. Its giving me an error "Error: unsupported type for column 'Call3' (NILSXP, classes = NULL)" Any idea how to solve these, as both my columns are strings?

Comment: hmm the way I defined the original data was 
mydata <- data.frame(Caller = c('Alice', 'Kate', 'Alice', 'Mary', 'Jane'), Receiver = c('Mary', 'Betty', 'Betty', 'Kate | Jane', 'Alice'))

But looks like the error you received is a dplyr bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34054968/mutate-is-trying-to-extract-using-the-value-of-a-global-variable-when-using-th
The suggested temporary fix is using $'y' instead of $y, so maybe try doing that on the problematic column if it applies? What is column 'Call3' that you are using? You could also try converting the column into a factor otherwise.

Comment: Thanks @coyin, I had tried that 'fix' yesterday. It did not work for me.

Comment: I am using>  read.csv( data, header = False,  stringsAsFactors = False)

Comment: That's strange. I tried using characters instead of factors, and it worked for me. Does using the example below work for you?
mydata <- data.frame(Caller = c('Alice', 'Kate', 'Alice', 'Mary', 'Jane'), Receiver = c('Mary', 'Betty', 'Betty', 'Kate | Jane', 'Alice'))

Comment: I tried your code in full on example data as above. It worked. Exactly like I want the output! But on the original data its still no-go. Time for more data wrangle, I suppose. Will update.

Comment: try str(original_data) on the original data and see what the classes are, and how it differs from the example data above?

Comment: str gives me Characters. typeof gives me list.

Comment: Apart from the bug reported in above conversation, I also stumbled on this one. https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1044.

One of the errors on my part is that using Gsub and Tolower to 'normalise' the data seems to have been a bad idea. (I dont know why)

Once I knew the 'entire fault' was in the "group_by" aka dplyr, I tried the alternative under library(psych)::describeBy. Its pretty roundabout way of doing things, and certainly not advisable. Though (sort of) solved it for now, will keep this question open for Fixes or other methods.

And, thank you very much @coyin !!